# there is i changed my project version then i have faced this type of error

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, version-control, version

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_2evj7k5hzfnbe82a9xz4u7tkj.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_2evj7k5hzfnbe82a9xz4u7tkj$_run_closure2) values: [build_2evj7k5hzfnbe82a9xz4u7tkj$_run_closure2@7e17e140]

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 611ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Any one please help for solve this error..(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5tuS.png)